# superset - trino - clickhouse showing data wrongly encoded

Tags: presto, clickhouse, apache-superset, trino

We have events data stored in clickhouse DB, for querying and visualization we are using superset and trino being used for query processing and combining data sources.

Beside clickhouse we have postgresql which is working fine, however in clickhouse datasource we are seeing string fields as base64 encoded, when query clickhouse directly using datagrip it works fine but when trying to do via superset -> trino it is encoded.

Any ideas how this could be fixed?

[image]

Superset is using trino (sqlalchemy)

[image]

and this is how its defined in trino

```
connector.name=clickhouse
connection-url=jdbc:clickhouse://10.x.x.x:8123/
connection-user=default
connection-password=
```

Comment: What connector are you using for Superset?  

Part of the problem is that Superset does not support UInt64 or IP values natively, but converts them to strings in some cases, and at some point those values are being Base64 encoded.  (I don't know about Trino though)

Comment: @GeoffGenz using sqlalchemy, updated the question with the configs

Comment: What do you see when you run show create <table> in Trino? And have you tried querying it using Trino CLI and see what it is giving as output?  https://trino.io/docs/current/client/cli.html

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy it shows the fields as `varbinary`

Comment: Found in the docs about `clickhouse.map-string-as-varchar` let me try with this and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trino has the fields by default considered as `varbinary` by setting the connection property

```
clickhouse.map-string-as-varchar=true
```

Fixed the mapping issue to use String and FixedStrings

https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/clickhouse.html

[image]